# How can I do jquery dropdown price reflection

Tags: jquery, reflection, dropdown

Brand is selected at the first dropdown, and product at the second. I want to add price tag when I select a product. I want price tag to be displayed, when a product is selected. How can I price the products?

```js
var ustKategori = '[{"ID":0,"KategoriAdi":"Taşeren Su"}, {"ID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı Su"}, {"ID":2,"KategoriAdi":"Taşkesti Su"}]';
var altKategori = '[{"ustKategoriID":0,"KategoriAdi":"Taşeren 19 lt Damacana   7 usd"}, {"ustKategoriID":0,"KategoriAdi":"Taşeren 19 lt Pet Tek Kullanımlık  5 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":0,"KategoriAdi":"Taşeren 200 ml Bardak (60 lı) 5 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":0,"KategoriAdi":"Taşeren 300 ml Bardak (40 lı) 4 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 19 lt Damacana 7 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 15 lt Cam Damacana 12 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 19 lt Pet Tek Kullanımlık 7 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 10 lt Pet (2 li) 4 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 5 lt Pet (4 lü) 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 1.5 lt Pet (12 li) 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 1 lt Pet (12 li) 4 usd"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 750 ml Cam (12 li) 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 500 ml (24 lü) 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":1,"KategoriAdi":"Buzdağı 330 ml Cam  (24 lü) 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":2,"KategoriAdi":"Taşkesti 19 lt Damacana 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":2,"KategoriAdi":"Taşkesti 15 lt Cam Damacana 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":2,"KategoriAdi":"Taşkesti 8 lt Cam Damacana 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":2,"KategoriAdi":"Taşkesti 5 lt Cam Damacana 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":2,"KategoriAdi":"Taşkesti 750 ml Cam Şişe (12 li) 4 tl"},{"ustKategoriID":2,"KategoriAdi":"Taşkesti 330 ml Cam Şişe (24 lü) 4 tl"}]';

var json_data = JSON.parse(ustKategori);
var json_data2 = JSON.parse(altKategori);
$("select#ustKategori").append('<option value="-1" label="AltKategori Seçiniz">AltKategori Seçiniz</option>');
for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {
  var option = $("<option>");
  option.attr("value", json_data[i]["ID"]);
  option.attr("label", json_data[i]["KategoriAdi"]);
  option.html(json_data[i]["KategoriAdi"]);
  $("select#ustKategori").append(option);
}

$('#ustKategori').on('change', function() {
  $("select#altKategori").html('');
  var SelectedID = $("#ustKategori option:selected").val();
  for (var i = 0; i < json_data2.length; i++) {
    if (json_data2[i]["ustKategoriID"] == SelectedID) {
      var option = $("<option>");
      option.attr("value", json_data2[i]["ustKategoriID"]);
      option.attr("label", json_data2[i]["KategoriAdi"]);
      option.html(json_data2[i]["KategoriAdi"]);
      $("select#altKategori").append(option);
    }
  }
  if ($("select#altKategori option").length > 0) {
    $("select#altKategori").show();
  } else {
    $("select#altKategori").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ustKategori">
</select>
<select id="altKategori">
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label  id="price"> i want to price here</label>
```

Comment: this is codes  https://jsfiddle.net/gxho4tcd/2/

Comment: You do not have price in your `json objects` as a separate field. you have them in the "KategoriAdi" field. So you have  to edit your altKategori  `json` and add price to it.